# is it possible to mock transient fields in tests?

Tags: testing, mockito, serializable, transient

I have a class that contains a transient field. But the other part of the class is serializable.
In the tests I mock the field and the class and use the mocked class object in a deep copy function which looks like below:

```
try {
      final ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(bytesOut);
      // serialize and pass the object
      objectOut.writeObject(original);
      objectOut.flush();
      final ByteArrayInputStream bytesIn =
          new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesOut.toByteArray());
      objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(bytesIn);
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      final T clone = (T) objectIn.readObject();
      // return the new object
      return clone;
    }
catch () {...}
```

the writeObject(original) method is supposed to write all non-transient and non-static fields. But I've got an error saying java.io.NotSerializableException for the mock transient field. I wonder if the transient field cannot be recognised in the tests? I use mockito as my framework.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "I mock the field and the class" ?

I just whipped up a quick test based on this dummy class:

```
public class DummyClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4991860764538033995L;

    transient private ChildClass child;

    ...
}
```

`ChildClass` is just an empty (non-`Serializable`) class. The test looks like this:

```
...
DummyClass dc = new DummyClass();
ChildClass mockChild  = mock(ChildClass.class);
dc.setChild(mockChild);
copier.copy(dc);
```

... and that doesn't throw any NotSerializableException.

What are you trying to test? The deep-copier or the class that is passed to it?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried to test using a thread which contains a parameter of a deep copy of the DummyClass, which has a transient child object. So I get the exception when I create a new DummyThread with a DummyClass object dc which is also a mock because this class contains a bunch of fields.